# AutoMapper nested mapping with DI

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, autofac

Mapping of nested objects is pretty straightforward with AutoMapper as long as there is a Map definition for the nested objects as well. I am facing an issue with implementing a Map between 2 objects, one of which **does not and cannot have a parameter-less constructor**. Let's say the Order object is such as below. The services are injected by autofac constructor dependency injection.

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailsService _orderDetailsService;

    public Order(IOrderDetailsService orderDetailsService)
    {
        _orderDetailsService = orderDetailsService;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized] private IEnumerable<OrderDetails> _details;

    public IEnumerable<OrderDetails> Details
    {
        get
        {
            _details = _orderDetailsService.GetDetailsByOrderId(Id);
            return _details;
        }
        set { _details = value; }
    }

}

public class OrderDetails
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
    public OrderDetails(IOrderService orderService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public string DetailInfo { get; set; }

    public Order Order
    {
        get { return _orderService.GetOrderById(OrderId); }
    }
}
```

And if there was a View Model such as below:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderDetailsViewModel> Details { get; set; } 
}

public class OrderDetailsViewModel
{
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public string DetailInformation { get; set; }
}
```

How would we go about Mapping Order to OrderViewModel and vice versa?

Comment: I updated my answer--please let me know if that's any better than my previous solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order` to `OrderViewModel` and `OrderDetails` to `OrderDetailsViewModel` should be straightforward:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>()       
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));

Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDetails, OrderDetailsViewModel>()     
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DetailInformation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DetailInfo))
```

The issue is mapping *back* to `Order`. Before attempting to do this, I would read [Jimmy Bogard's article on two way mapping](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/). Basically AutoMapper was created to map *to* DTOs from domain objects, not the other way around.

Nevertheless, if you want to map back to `Order` and `OrderDetails`, you could use AutoMapper's ability to construct types using an IoC container. This involves registering the container with AutoMapper so that it knows how to resolve types.

As Jimmy points out in the comments, you'll also need to register `Order` and `OrderDetails`. I'm not all that familiar with Autofac, but I had success with this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<OrderDetailsService>().As<IOrderDetailsService>();
builder.RegisterType<OrderService>().As<IOrderService>();

/* Register Order and OrderDetails to use themselves: */
builder.RegisterType<Order>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<OrderDetails>().AsSelf();

var container = builder.Build();

/* Register the container with AutoMapper */
Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);
```

Now all you need to do is use `.ReverseMap` and `.ConstructUsingServiceLocator` to let AutoMapper know to use the IoC container to create the `Order` and `OrderDetails` objects:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>()       
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Details, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDetails, OrderDetailsViewModel>()     
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DetailInformation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DetailInfo))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()     
    .ForSourceMember(dest => dest.DetailInformation, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DetailInfo, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I think this is a good option. Thanks to Jimmy Bogard in the comments for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Since Order and OrderDetails do not have a parameter-less constructor, I don't see how the second approach (your suggested one) would work. Is that addressed in any way that's not mentioned?

Comment: Hmm, well I addressed `Order` but you're correct about `OrderDetails`. Guess the second approach won't work.

Comment: You can use ConstructUsingServiceLocator after CreateMap too.

Comment: @JimmyBogard: I tried that, and it looked like AutoMapper was trying to construct the `Order`/`OrderDetails` class using the service locator, not the services that the constructors needed. I could have been using it incorrectly though

Comment: Yes, you'd need to register those objects with the container, too. I do that quite frequently with ViewModels.

Comment: @JimmyBogard: Thanks, I was able to come up with a decent answer after your tip.

Comment: My implementation is exactly as you have proposed with the only difference that I am registering services as part of an autofac Module but I am getting an exception with the following message "Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args". After registering the container with AutoMapper, I can see that the container is set with filled component registery as well. Not sure, what's missing.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: The only other difference is that my services have to be registered as InstancePerLifeTimeScope due to circular dependency setup with autofac.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not very familiar with Autofac so I don't think I'll be able to be much help. I'll keep digging though.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It turns out that the AutoMapper's configuration needs to be setup to use the proper container before all the maps are created for this to work. After making that happen, the original problem has been resolved. I can see that the services are being injected into the classes properly, But now, I am getting an AutoMapper mapping exception, Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListInterator' OrderDetails to type IList. I noticed the destination is listed as Order.Details.Details. In my implementation, both the viewmodel and the entity are using IEnumerable and not IList.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker As soon as I change the implementation of Order.Details to IList, the mapping happens successfully. Why would IEnumerable cause this issue?

Comment: @boosts: Which way are you mapping? `Order` --> `OrderViewModel` or  the other way around?

Comment: OrderViewModel --> Order is the one that throws the exception if IEnumerable is used.

Comment: @boosts:Odd, because `Order.Details` should be ignored right?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker No, it's the nested mapping that should work. OrderViewModel --> Order should produce an Order object and it's Details. Looking at the code above I can see that the setter on the Details does not exist and there is not backing field for it either. My apologies for not including that in my original question. I will make the modifications.

Comment: @boosts: ok, i'll take a look

Comment: @boosts: Check out this bug ticket about the issue you're seeing: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/555